# How can I use BLAS functionality with Python's Theano library?

Tags: python, windows, theano, blas

I'm trying to run an example https://github.com/mnielsen/neural-networks-and-deep-learning/blob/master/src/network3.py from machine learning book http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/index.html under Windows10 which needs the Theano library.

I'm foreign to Python, so all I could do was to slavishly follow the installation instructions http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/install_windows.html.

When I import the module, the system complains about `try_blas_2wsay3pw.exe` crashing.

The only fix that I can come up with is setting the environment variable:

```
set THEANO_FLAGS=blas.ldflags=
```

which has the effect that Theano falls back to NumPy's C-API and emits a warning:

```
WARNING (theano.tensor.blas): Using NumPy C-API based implementation for BLAS functions.
```

I have `mkl-service` installed so in theory I should be able to use BLAS.

What can I do about this problem?

Comment: I have the same issue. Someone please help :D

Answer (score 1):

Though in official documentation it says your python should be <3.6, but actually Theano runs well with Python 3.6, it's not the problem root.

The problem is actually caused by a bug in Theano's `configdefaults.py` file.  From line 1403 to 1407, wrong MKL lib name is set to `mkl_gnu_thread` which should be `mkl_intel_thread` instead for Windows.

I've already reported this issue [here](https://github.com/Theano/Theano/issues/6599)

Answer (score 0):

Theano doesn't support python3.6:

> Your python should be 2.7* or ( >= 3.4 and < 3.6 )

from http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/install_windows.html

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: This isn't a link-only answer. The link is to cite the source of the quote. (That said, there's no evidence that the OP is using 3.6 though?)